# Different behavior of flask app in supervisor than in screen (can't switch user?)

Tags: python, flask, supervisord, gnu-screen

I have the following a flask app `builder/builder.py` started via the following `start.sh` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export FLASK_APP=builder/builder.py
export FLASK_DEBUG=true
flask run  --host=0.0.0.0 > builder.log 2> builder.err
```

If I run `./start.sh` in screen as user `chris`, everything works fine. However, in supervisor, I get the error that no flask app was found in the python path.

How is it possible that I get different behavior executing the same thing? I'd like to use supervisor for higher reliability.
My supervisor config in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/builder.conf` looks like this:

```
[program:builder]
user = chris
environment = PATH="/home/chris/path:%(ENV_PATH)s"
directory = /home/chris/path
command = bash -c start.sh
stopasgroup=true
```

**Edit:**

I tried using an absolute path in `export FLASK_APP=..` but then the relative paths in the flask app didn't work anymore. I don't want to change all that.

Instead, adding `environment` and `directory` to my config (see above) helped and supervisor now executes the flask app. The remaining problem is that it seems, it doesn't execute it correctly as user `chris` - despite the part in  the config! Is it possible that supervisor still performs the commands as `root`since I started it as `root`? I get the same error messages when running the program as `root` instead of `chris`.

Comment: Try changing path to flask app from relative to absolute.

Comment: I tried absolute paths and more but still have problems. Please see above.